# CSS Transitions for drop down menu not working

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have the following two-level menu:

```
 <ul class="mid-nav-top-ul">

            <li class="mid-nav-top-li"><a class="mid-nav-top-a">Trading News</a>
                <ul class="mid-nav-two-ul">
                    <li class="mid-nav-two-li"><a class="mid-nav-two-a" href="#">Articles</a></li>
                    <li class="mid-nav-two-li"><a class="mid-nav-two-a" href="#">Stocks</a></li>
                    <li class="mid-nav-two-li"><a class="mid-nav-two-a" href="#">Forex</a></li>
                    <li class="mid-nav-two-li"><a class="mid-nav-two-a" href="#">Commodities</a></li>
                    <li class="mid-nav-two-li"><a class="mid-nav-two-a" href="#">Options</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
```

I have the following CSS to make it a drop-down sort of menu:

```
.mid-nav-two-ul{height: 0px; -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;  transition: height 0.5s;}
.mid-nav-top-ul:hover .mid-nav-two-ul{height: auto;}
```

It doesn't take into account the transition - it drops down/ changes height instantaneously.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/css-transition-height-0-to-height-auto

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, setting the height of the menu `ul` won't necessarily affect what's visible. If the overflow is set to `hidden`, e.g. `overflow: hidden;` then the height change will affect content inside because we then understand what to do with 'overflowing' content.

Secondly, we cannot animate the `height` property directly, you must use `max-height`. You can then set `max-height` to be some arbitrary value that is guaranteed to be higher than your `ul` list will ever be.

Here's working code:

```
.mid-nav-two-ul
{
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s; 
    transition: max-height 0.5s;

}

.mid-nav-top-ul:hover .mid-nav-two-ul
{
    max-height: 1000px;
}
```

[Here's a working JSFiddle for you.](http://jsfiddle.net/LbuLn8dy/)